# Getting 412 status code while changing category of a mail to Red

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I am using /messages graph api to change category of a mail which is in inbox.Sometimes I am getting 412 status code and some times category is changing successfully.I tried by passing If-Match(passing value as changeKey from get messages response) and If-Range(passing value as new Date().toISOString()).Even though I am getting 412 status code for some times.Below I am attaching the object which I am passing to request module.Could you please explain me how to solve this issue?

```
    const accessToken = await redisClient.getKey(GRAPH_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    const sharedMailId = this.config.SHARED_MAIL_ID;
    const options = {
      url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' + sharedMailId + '/messages/' + 
            data.messageId,
      method: 'PATCH',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
      },
      body: {
        'categories': data.category,
      },
      json: true,
    };
```